# ORA-00905: missing keyword during Merge statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting this error help me:- ORA-00905: missing keyword

Merge statement in sql

```
MERGE INTO TEMP1 T
USING (SELECT CHAR_VAR,VCHAR,VAR_CHAR2 FROM VAR_CHECK WHERE CHAR_VAR='Steven' AND VCHAR='King') S
ON (T.AUTHOR=S.CHAR_VAR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T.SNAME=S.VAR_CHAR2
WHEN NOT MATCHED
INSERT (T.AUTHOR,T.TOPIC,T.SNAME) VALUES (S.CHAR_VAR,S.VCHAR,S.VAR_CHAR2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The keyword that is missing is `THEN` after `WHEN NOT MATCHED`:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP1 T
USING (SELECT CHAR_VAR,VCHAR,VAR_CHAR2 FROM VAR_CHECK WHERE CHAR_VAR='Steven' AND VCHAR='King') S
ON (T.AUTHOR=S.CHAR_VAR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T.SNAME=S.VAR_CHAR2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (T.AUTHOR,T.TOPIC,T.SNAME) VALUES (S.CHAR_VAR,S.VCHAR,S.VAR_CHAR2);
```

Comment: Is it possible to merge more than 1 records from source table?

ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables


MERGE INTO TEMP1 T
USING (SELECT CHAR_VAR,VCHAR,VAR_CHAR2 FROM VAR_CHECK) S
ON (T.AUTHOR=S.CHAR_VAR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T.SNAME=S.VAR_CHAR2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (T.AUTHOR,T.TOPIC,T.SNAME) VALUES (S.CHAR_VAR,S.VCHAR,S.VAR_CHAR2);

Comment: It is. This error is thrown when one source row matches more than one target rows. You must modify the matching condition so one source row matches at most one target row.

Comment: @Husqvik, Wouldn't the cause of ORA-30926 be the opposite of what you say, that is, more than one source row matching the same target row that causes this error?  (Assuming that by source you mean the `USING` clause and by target you mean the `INTO` clause.)

Comment: @Dave Costa - my mistake, you're right, if a target row is matched for update and updated and then some other source row matches again the updated row the error is thrown.